# returning false from JavaScript Does not stop the HTML page from Executing

Tags: javascript, html

i have a list in my HTML page with the following code.

```
        <li><a href="HomePage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="loginCheck();">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="MakePayment.aspx" onclick="loginCheck();">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="HomePage.html" onclick="logout();">Log Out</a></li>
```

my log in check function is as follows.

```
 function validate()
   {
   some validations done here.if found true change the variable log in to true.
   login = true;
   }
 function loginCheck() {

       if (!login) {
           alert("Log In to continue operations");
           return false;
       }
```

the page gives an alert `Log In to continue operations`. But still moves to the next page which was clicked. How can i stop this ?

Comment: Your event handler is not actually returning `false`. You have to include the `return` statement in the "onclick" attribute value.

Comment: You can also prevent the default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `return` in the `onclick` handler, otherwise the value isn't actually returned.
Do it like this and it will work:

```
<li><a href="HomePage.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Register</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="return loginCheck();">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="MakePayment.aspx" onclick="return loginCheck();">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="HomePage.html" onclick="return logout();">Log Out</a></li>
```